# What is <!--> for?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I wonder what this tag in script stands for `<!--> //-->`
I've noticed it in some usage of javascript, but not always.
Is this necessary or can you just keep it out and what is it's major use?

Comment: It's the HTML comment tag, and it was used in the past to avoid js code being displayed by browsers that didn't understand javascript. You can safely remove it nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

Before javascript existed, browsers did not know what `<script>` meant. The tag didn't exist yet. So those browsers would attempt to output the javascript directly! To work around that, we would comment out the javascript with `<!--` html comments `-->`. However, the ending html comment `-->` is a javascript syntax error, so we have to comment that out with `//` javascript comments. Nowadays, browsers are smarter and can handle these edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

Those are to create comments in [XML and HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/The_Importance_of_Correct_HTML_Commenting).

```
<!-- this will not show -->
But this will.
```

They are included in scripts to hide the code from browsers (technically, this can be a number of different devices, but I'm using "browser" for short) which don't allow for JavaScript.

```
<script><!--
doSomethingJavaScripty();
// -->
</script>
```

This means the browser without JavaScript will not accidentally display `doSomethingJavaScripty();`. It is often paired with a `noscript` tag (which a browser that supports JS will safely ignore).

This is technically optional. Often times it is a relic of a now-forgotten past, but it is conceivable that it might be useful at some point. It might happen, for example, that you eventually want a service to read and parse your webpage. In such a case, adherence to good practice will prove beneficial. But, even in that circumstance, it has become more common (thankfully) to move to something called "[unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)."

Answer (score 0):

its used when developers wants to be on safe side, that if browser doesnot support javascript then the code will not be rendered as text, it will become comment